# Why Hadoop MapReduce process run backwards many times

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I run my map reduce program on Hadoop system, I find my program perhaps will never stop. When the reduce process reach one percentage, the map stage will go down from 100% to 25%, and the reduce will start from 0% again, but this phenomenon seems like go into a frustrated loop.

```
map 100% reduce 16%
map 100% reduce 22%
map 100% reduce 31%
map 100% reduce 33%
map 25% reduce 0%
map 70% reduce 0%
map 100% reduce 0%
map 100% reduce 13%
map 100% reduce 20%
map 100% reduce 28%
map 100% reduce 29%
map 100% reduce 30%
map 100% reduce 31%
map 23% reduce 0%
map 73% reduce 0%
map 100% reduce 0%
map 100% reduce 12%
map 100% reduce 22%
map 100% reduce 26%
map 100% reduce 27%
map 100% reduce 28%
map 100% reduce 29%
map 100% reduce 26%
map 100% reduce 17%
map 100% reduce 18%
map 100% reduce 19%
map 100% reduce 18%
map 100% reduce 19%
map 100% reduce 20%
map 100% reduce 18%
map 100% reduce 19%
map 99% reduce 19%
map 99% reduce 20%
```

Is there some methods to solve it.

My hadoop program configuration:

```
-D mapred.job.map.capacity=9000 \
-D mapred.job.reduce.capacity=6000 \
-D mapred.map.tasks=8000 \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=6000
```

Comment: You have map tasks that are failing.

Comment: By the way, any property starting with `mapred.` is deprecated, and you never set the map tasks yourself. The type and size of input data determine that

Comment: @cricket_007，I am sorry for hiding the program details for some privacy, I really set the mapper and reducer in my mapred script.

Comment: @BinaryNerd,  I think so, but the 100% is  a false appearance?

Comment: You can have multiple maps and multiple reduces... Without seeing your actual command, code, and size of data, we can't really say... Also, go look at the YARN UI. Are there failed tasks?

Comment: @Douyg added some insight on why your logs behaving. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

> When the reduce process reach one percentage,

The sorting and shuffling stage of `mapreduce` program may start; which is counted against `reducer` progress.

> the map stage will go down from 100% to 25%, and the reduce will start
>   from 0% again

When map is saying `100%` on log, it may not be `100%` completed at that point of time. As soon as overall map process exceeds `99.5%`; it is displayed as `100%` (Even `99.6, .7, .8` all translate into `100%`).

Now dropping to `25%` may be the case when one or more mapper failed just at the **last** moment. The value `25%` signifies that approximately `75%` of data processing by mapper is wasted.

To come out of the scenario, please provide more details on what kind of data you are trying to solve and how you have arrived to the decision to set number of mapper/reducer vs your cluster capacity and data volume.

Comment: I have found the reason for the mapred process reciprocating again and again. It is that I insert too much different possible counter in my reducer program, almost  thousands of different type counters. When the reduce tasks failed, map tasks are reboot again, and so on. Thanks!

Comment: You have found the code bug which is causing this. I have given the reason on why the logs looks weird, which was your query.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage come from different jobs, executed in parallel

```
hive.exec.parallel=true
```